# How to sort excel values with numbers in end

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a macro which reads file names from a folder. The problem is that when file names are in series like A1,A2.....A200.pdf, as in this image:

[image]

then it reads in Excel as A1,A10,A100,A101.....A109,A11,A110.....A119,A20, as in this image:

[image]

How can I sort this so that the value in Excel comes as same as folder file names, or is there a way I can sort in Excel itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort this in Excel with a helper column. Create a new column and calculate the length of your filenames in that "=LEN(A1)". Then use two-level sort to sort your filenames. Data -> Sort: Use length in the first level and the filenames in the second level.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening ofcourse of because different sorting algorithm in both these cases (Windows Explorer and Excel) [Refer to this article](https://www.meridiandiscovery.com/how-to/why-windows-sorts-numeric-file-names-differently/) if you want to understand.

To solve your problem, one of the ways is to pull out only the numeric part of file names in a different cell (say column B) and then sort based on those numbers.

If I can assume that the pattern of the files names is AXXX.pdf i.e. one letter A, then number, and 4 characters for file extension. You can use this function

=VALUE(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-5))

This works by pulling out some number of characters from in between the string. As per assumption, the number starts from 2nd place that's why the second parameter is 2. Then to decide, how many characters you pull, you know that all the characters except 'A' (1 char) and '.pdf' (4 chars) make the number. So, take the lenght of the whole name and reduce 5 characters. You get your number part which you can sort.

This will be your result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K Corrected now

Answer (score 1):

Another option, you can use the `RegEx` object to extract the Numeric digits "captured" inside the file name.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortFileNames()

Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1") ' replaces "Sheet1| with your sheet's name
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B" & i).Value = RetractNumberwithRegex(.Range("A" & i)) ' call the Regex function
    Next i
End With

End Sub

'========================================================================

Function RetractNumberwithRegex(Rng As Range) As String
    ' function uses the Regex object to substract the Numeric values inside

    Dim Reg1 As Object
    Dim Matches As Object

    Set Reg1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Reg1
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,20}"  ' any size numeric string (up to 20 digits length)
    End With

    Set Matches = Reg1.Execute(Rng.Value2)
    If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
        RetractNumberwithRegex = Matches.Item(0)
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to change the file names in your Excel list to have leading zeroes. Instead of A19, refer to the file as A019 and it will sort correctly. Convert the file names using this formula in a helper column.

```
=Left($A2, 1) & Right("000" & Mid($A2, 2, 3), 3)
```

Note that the 3 zeroes and string lengths of 3 are all related to each other. To create fixed length numbers of 4 digits, just use 4 zeroes and increase both string lengths to 4.

Copy the formula down from row 2 to the end. Copy the helper column, paste `Values` in place and, when everything is perfect, replace the original column with the helper.

In order to accommodate a fixed number of digits following the number the above formula may be tweaked. The formula below will accommodate 4 extra characters which follow the number, for example ".pdf" (including the period).

```
=Left($A2, 1) & Right("000" & Mid($A2, 2, 7), 7)
```

Comment: your formula is wrong. Mid should have 3 arguments and it doesn't look complete for what you want to do

Comment: @nitigyan Yes, you are right. In Excel, the Mid function requires the length argument. Thank you for pointing this out. Logically the length should be equal to the number of digits which should be equal to the number of zeroes in the prefix. So, if the OP wanted a 4-digit number the second part of the formula would look like this, `Right("0000" & Mid($A2, 2, 4), 4)`

Comment: @YowE3K Not quite, but you are correct in pointing out that the OP doesn't really want to sort the numbers "at the end" as the question's title suggests. My suggestion will work so long as all extensions are of the same length. If not, it can be modified to accommodate extensions of varying length, all of which doesn't change the gist of my suggestion which is to use leading zeroes.

Comment: @Variatus It's still not correct. Applying the formula gives following results for different file names:
A1.pdf -> A1.p, 
A2.pdf -> A2.p,
A11.pdf -> A11.
A111.pdf -> A111

More over it's NOT SCALABLE as it will only work for one particular lenght of file name i.e. either single digit number or double digit. 

You will have to do this =LEFT(A2,1)&TEXT(MID(A2,2,LEN(A2)-4),"000000")&RIGHT(A2,4)

Comment: @nitigyan Why don't you try my formula out. You might be amazed.

Comment: @YeoE3K My formula takes only one character from the left, not four.

Comment: @YeoE3K What's wrong with you people? The first formula is correct. The second one explains how to tweak it to include suffixes, My above comment explains how to tweak it to create 4-digit numbers. And I can absolutely assure you that all Windows Explorers I ever used sort alphabetically, meaning they sort "A10" before "A2".

Comment: Your second formula is correct. It does the right 0 padding for file names upto A999.pdf but your first formula is still wrong.
@YowE3K The sorting in Windows Explorer is actually dependent of Windows settings. As per https://www.meridiandiscovery.com/how-to/why-windows-sorts-numeric-file-names-differently/ There is a registry key that can be modified to enable or disable this type of sorting, which is only possible post Win XP version

Comment: @nitigyan Ahh - I will have to go have a read of that.  I've nearly learned to live with it now, making sure I always use constant length numeric fields, but I might switch back again if it is easy to do.

Comment: @Variatus I now see, you mean the first formula is meant to be used with file names without extension. Apologies, but your answer doesn't make it clear. It will help if you make it more clear. Removed by downvote :)

Comment: @nitigyan Thank you. My first formula responded to the title of the question.